# Database design. One-to-many extra attributes

Tags: sql, normalization, one-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

Let's say we have a `Player` table and a `Team` table and one-to-many relationship between them (a `Player` is a member of one `Team` only or a member of none)

So I have a nullable `team_id` field in `Player` table, referencing to a `Team` table.

But now I have to store an extra information about a player's position in the team. Like:

- `isCaptain`
- `number`
- etc...

What is the right (normal) way to implement this?

My best ideas is an extra table:

`Player` one-to-one (NULL) `PlayerTeam` many-to-one (not NULL) `Team`

Comment: If a player can only have one team, then wouldn't these extra attributes make sense on the player table itself? Unless you can potentially have different type of PlayerTeam metadata configurations or something.

Comment: I'm just not sure if it's right to pollute the player table with extra `NULL`able fields. And how can I be sure that when `team_id` is `NULL`, all extra fields are also `NULL`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend your own suggestion making a new table:

```
id | player_id | team_id | role_id | number
```

and then make player_id unique, and team_id not null.

This will keep the player table clean and your database normalized.

Comment: I like it.  And have a unique segmented index on player_id, team_id, role_id, number to ensure no duplicate relationships.

Answer (score 0):

If the player can only have one team, you can/should store that information directly on `Player`.

On the other hand, if you plan to store historical information, `Player` - `Team` might become a many-to-many, in which case the `PlayerTeam` join table would be the right place to put that information.